# How can I save the Output to a Dataframe?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, survey

How can I save the Output to a Panda Dataframe?

This Code will print a Survey with different Questions and Answers. If you click the "Submit" Button a summary of all Answers to all the different questions will be printed out.
My Problem is: I want the Answers to get saved in an Panda DataFrame. Or even better in an Database, with Dates to the different Answers.

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, State, MATCH, ALL

app = Dash(__name__)

questionnaire = {
    1: {
        'type': 'choice',
        'question':
        '''
        Question 1
        ''',
        'options': ['-2', '-1', '+1', '+2']
    },
    2: {
        'type': 'choice',
        'question':
        '''
        Question 2
        ''',
        'options': ['-2', '-1', '+1', '+2']
    },
    3: {
        'type': 'choice',
        'question':
        '''
        Question 3
        ''',
        'options': ['-2', '-1', '+1', '+2']
    },
    4: {
        'type': 'choice',
        'question':
        '''
        Question 4
        ''',
        'options': ['-2', '-1', '+1', '+2']
    },
}


def generate(k, v):
    if 'choice':
            return html.Div([html.P(str(k)+'. '+v['question']), dcc.RadioItems(id={'index': k, 'type': v['type'], 'category':'questionnaire'}, options={i: i for i in v['options']})])


app.layout = html.Div([generate(k, v) for k, v in questionnaire.items()] +
                      [html.Br(), btn := html.Button('Submit'), answers := html.Div()])


@app.callback(
    Output(
        {
            'category': 'questionnaire',
            'type': 'choice+blank',
            'index': MATCH
        }, 'disabled'),
    Input(
        {
            'category': 'questionnaire',
            'type': 'choice+blank',
            'index': MATCH
        }, 'value'))


@app.callback(
    Output(
        btn, 'disabled'),
    Input(
        {
            'category': 'questionnaire',
            'type': ALL,
            'index': ALL
        }, 'value'))



@app.callback(Output(answers, 'children'), Input(btn, 'n_clicks'), [
    State(
        {
            'category': 'questionnaire',
            'type': ALL,
            'index': ALL
        }, 'id'),
    State(
        {
            'category': 'questionnaire',
            'type': ALL,
            'index': ALL
        }, 'value')
], prevent_initial_call=True)
def collect(n_clicks, index, answer):
    return str([v | {'answer': answer[i]} for i, v in enumerate(index)])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you please share full code for better understanding and the context,

Comment: this is full code